# React onClick cannot handle multiple methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, handler

I have the following React component:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState()

  // handle these data here and display them

  return <ChildComponent sendData={setData} data={data} />
}

const ChildComponent = ({ data, sendData }) => {
  const toggleStrikethrough = e => {
    e.target.style.textDecoration = e.target.style.textDecoration === 'line-through' ? '' : 'line-through'
    const { booking } = e.currentTarget.dataset

    sendData(booking)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(booking => (
        <button key={index} data-booking={booking.name} onClick={toggleStrikethrough}>
          {booking.name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

AS you can see I have parent component which receive the data from child component but my issue is with the child component, when I try to manipulate the style **with** sending data in same time it does not work, but only one of them work eg. if I remove `sendData(booking)` the styles change and if  I remove the style manipulating in the same function `toggleStrikethrough()` then the data sent to parent component but they cannot work together, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is it's rerendering after the parent's state is getting updated.

When you do `sendData` it updates the state of the parent. And when the `state` updates it re-renders the component, including all the children.

Ideally, you'd want to style your components based on data stored in the state.

Comment: I have already tried to use another custom component <Button />  where it handle the style manipulation, but it is the same actually and didn't want to work

Answer (score 0):

I think React is likely re-rendering your buttons without the text decorations.
What you probably want is to modify the elements in the data passed down to ChildComponent so that "selected"/"checked" is a part of the state (boolean probably works).

e.g. if your data currently looks like: [{ name: "foo" }, { name: "bar" }], you can manipulate it so that it becomes [{ name: "foo" }, { name: "bar", checked: true }].

So you can do something like this:

```jsx
const ParentComponent = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState()
  // handle these data here and display them

  return <ChildComponent sendData={setData} data={data} />
}

const ChildComponent = ({ data, sendData }) => {
  const toggleStrikethrough = e => {
    const { booking } = e.currentTarget.dataset

    sendData({ ...booking, checked: true })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(booking => (
        <button key={index} data-booking={booking.name} onClick={toggleStrikethrough} styles={{ textDecoration: booking.checked ? "line-through" : "initial"}}>
          {booking.name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The funny thing is that I'm also mapping over the child components frmo the parent component like: data.map((data) => <ChildComponent .../>) so this one will not work, any other ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, if you're still stuck it might be helpful if you post your code up in a sandbox/codepen cause right now there's a lot of missing information.